# What does the prompt '...' in python 3 mean?

Tags: python-3.x, printing, prompt

As an exercise we need to explain what happens when we leave an open paranthesesis in a print statement.

Doing so does not give us an error nor a value, the resulting line gives us a prompt consisting of dots instead of arrows. Does this situation/prompt have a name and can someone explain?

for example:

```
>>>print('Hello'

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official name is [secondary prompt](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode). It is used when inputting incomplete constructs, for example not closing any set of parentheses or when defining a function.

Answer (score 0):

The three greater-than signs (`>>>`) prompts for the next command, which the interpreter can process at once. The three dots (`...`), in its turn, prompts the continuation lines, such as `print(`: interpreter can't process your command at once, because it, in this case, doesn't know the arguments you want to pass to the function.